# Looking for the name of a type of painting

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the name of a type of painting that typically contains a crowd of people posed along a plane? Usually they're all focused on one point or an event that is happening in the painting.

I've seen lots of of examples but I can't find any good ones at the moment. The best I could find is [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aZeno_of_Elea_Tibaldi_or_Carducci_Escorial.jpg).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You call this **isocephaly** (all heads looking in the same direction).

From [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/isocephalic):

> (of a composition) having the heads of all figures on approximately the same level.

Comment: Oooh, nice find!

Comment: Awesome! I thought I'd never find out :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't recall a specific technical name for that particular construction in painting. In sculpture, low depth of field is *bas relief*, but I have never heard that used in conjunction with painting.

In the example you gave, it is probably an artifact of using stage props or backgrounds.

(I have heard people discuss this (I have an art background), but never use a specific technical term.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there's a term for what you're trying to explain, but that painting you linked looks to be an example of [History Painting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_painting).

You might want to look through Wikipedia's list of [Art Genres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category%3aArt_genres). Nothing jumped out at me…